# Predicting churn of customer using Machine Learning with lag

Tags: python, data-science, data-science-experience

I have data of 5000 customers over time series (monthly) which looks like:

[image]

This is my first time dealing with time series data. Can someone explain some strategies for Churn prediction probability (3 months, 6 months) in advance?

I am confused because for every customer churning probability 3 or 6 months in advance will be zero (according to target). So should I see some trends or create lag variables?

But I still don't know if regression, what will be the target variable.

Answer (score -1):

you can use lag function and then define churn and use predictive model to churn. As I can see buying product category, so you can take lag for last 3 month for unique customer id and then define the churn for 3 months

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer, i know you don't have enough reputation yet but have patience !! I appreciate your efforts for answer. thanks